# Regex to capture <img src> regardless of position in java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to figure out a regex pattern for the following img src tag

`<img src="attachment.jpg" alt="attachment.jpg" />`

I just want the **img src tag** here for instance the 'attachment.jpg", however is there such a pattern that can find the img src if its in different locations throughout the request, for instance like this

`<img height="" weight="" src="attachment.jpg" alt="attachment.jpg" />`

So within my returned pattern it would always find <img src="attachment.jpg" and then return me the "attachment.jpg" regardless of position

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0):

```java
String regex = "<img .*src=\"([^\\s]+)\"";
Pattern pttrn = Pattern.compile(regex);
String str = "<img height=\"\" weight=\"\" src=\"attachment.jpg\" alt=\"attachment.jpg\" />";
Matcher mtchr = pttrn.matcher(str);
if (mtchr.find()) {
    System.out.println(mtchr.group(1));
}
String str2 = "<img src=\"attachment.jpg\" alt=\"attachment.jpg\" />";
mtchr = pttrn.matcher(str);
if (mtchr.find()) {
    System.out.println(mtchr.group(1));
}
```

The above regular expression searches for `<img` followed by a single space, followed by zero or more characters (any characters), followed by `src="` followed by one or more non-space characters and finally followed by `"`. The characters between the double quotes are stored in a group. Hence the contents of the group is what you wish to obtain.